# Windows 2003 heartbleed bug openssl fix

Tags: windows-server-2003, heartbleed

As recommended by [openssl.org](http://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140407.txt) I'm trying to update OpenSSL from 1.0.1e to 1.0.1g. Fixes for most linux distributions have already deployed, but, what should be done on windows? we are using win server 2003 x64; OpenSSL 1.0.1e was installed using "Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1g" installer from Shining Light Productions web site (http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). 1.0.1g installer is available from Shining Light people, but that is a full intaller, not an update. I don't want to screw up our SSL certificate configuration and I don't really know exactly what binaries/files should be replaced/edited and where can I find them. Thanks in advance for your help, any info will be  be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Thank you Ryan for your suggestion, Thomas Hruska, from Shining Light, nicely took the time to reply my email:

> "1.0.1e is binary compatible with 1.0.1g. Just make sure the web
>   server  is stopped before installing to avoid issues with overwriting
>   files in  use, which you have to do anyway after updating OpenSSL."

Comment: Contact the vendor (shinelight@shininglightpro.com) and ask them (I think it's just one dude, actually,) what the recommended upgrade process is...

Answer (score 1):

According to this page, the flaw has been fixed in the latest release (1.0.1g): http://www.pcworld.com/article/2140920/heartbleed-bug-in-openssl-puts-encrypted-communications-at-risk.html

(Of course, it could be wrong--if you claim to have installed this, when was it that you installed it? I know it's reaching but it's possible that they updated that release on the downloads page to include the fix without bumping up any version numbers.)